# Counting independent sets

Tags: algorithms, graphs, combinatorics, counting

I know the [Independent set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) is NP-complete. But could there be a more efficient way to count the exact number of different independent sets in an arbitrary, given graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this problem is well-known to be [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete). For more, you can see [this question on CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/10700/5693).

Comment: I understand that counting maximum independent sets is definitely #P-complete. Is it possible to reduce counting maximum independent sets to counting the total number of independent sets without a constraint on their size?

Comment: @MircoPaul Counting the number of independent sets is #P-complete, this is the result of Provan and Ball.